# Application error on heroku deployment: .. error occurred in the application and your page could not be served node.js?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I don't understand... my app is being deployed but it does not serve in the webpage, does anybody know whats wrong? I can't figure it out! everything appears to be fine I don't see where the error lies.

```
2014-05-05T12:47:54.828189+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=25006d4c-fc57-4404-827d-ba99c41e398d fwd="194.81.199.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T12:56:34.291229+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=9c5d12b3-e8c4-4bb3-a3ae-e9b317518e58 fwd="194.81.199.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T12:59:41.039340+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=89fe663e-628b-467f-ac3b-f3a53ddc1451 fwd="194.81.199.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T13:01:03.544661+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=bd53f160-115c-4558-a432-ed7b789c7bb7 fwd="194.81.199.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T13:01:53.971879+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=0d5c1d86-3ea6-46dc-b0e5-388635bde9f6 fwd="194.81.199.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T13:01:56.444851+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=dc2badca-0467-4761-bb7e-0a810cb101e8 fwd="194.81.199.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T13:01:58.391138+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=07eab76b-e59d-409e-b87a-b8efaeae05ee fwd="194.81.199.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T13:08:04+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-05-05T13:08:24+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-05-05T13:
08:24.978597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-05-05T13:08:24.842949+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy b5e6656 by plimbsuni@gmail.com
2014-05-05T13:08:24.842949+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v11 created by plimbsuni@gmail.com
2014-05-05T13:08:26.788722+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2014-05-05T13:08:28.707529+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! MotionTherapy@0.0.1 start: `node server.js`
2014-05-05T13:08:28.691357+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-05-05T13:08:28.708859+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2014-05-05T13:08:28.707846+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2014-05-05T13:08:28.707951+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the MotionTherapy@0.0.1 start script.
2014-05-05T13:08:28.708514+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the MotionTherapy package,
2014-05-05T13:08:28.707701+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 8
2014-05-05T13:08:28.708625+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2014-05-05T13:08:28.708733+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2014-05-05T13:08:28.708967+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2014-05-05T13:08:28.709068+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls MotionTherapy
2014-05-05T13:08:28.709206+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2014-05-05T13:08:28.709526+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
2014-05-05T13:08:28.709684+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2014-05-05T13:08:28.709841+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cwd /app
2014-05-05T13:08:28.709975+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
2014-05-05T13:08:28.710110+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
2014-05-05T13:08:28.710230+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2014-05-05T13:08:28.711774+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2014-05-05T13:08:28.711889+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
2014-05-05T13:08:28.711978+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2014-05-05T13:08:28.712194+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not ok code 0
2014-05-05T13:08:28.613033+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-05T13:08:28.613050+00:00 app[web.1]: > MotionTherapy@0.0.1 start /app
2014-05-05T13:08:28.613052+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2014-05-05T13:08:28.613054+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-05T13:08:28.690176+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-05T13:08:28.693873+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-05-05T13:08:28.693929+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-05-05T13:08:28.695957+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
2014-05-05T13:08:28.695960+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-05-05T13:08:28.695962+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-05-05T13:08:28.695963+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2014-05-05T13:08:28.695965+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:119:16)
2014-05-05T13:08:28.695967+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:906:3
2014-05-05T13:08:28.701805+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-05T13:08:30.178050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-05-05T13:08:30.179073+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-05-05T13:08:30.166994+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-05-05T13:08:33.497955+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-05-05T13:08:33.431728+00:00 app[web.1]: > MotionTherapy@0.0.1 start /app
2014-05-05T13:08:33.499529+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-05-05T13:08:33.497965+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-05-05T13:08:33.499531+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2014-05-05T13:08:33.499532+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:119:16)
2014-05-05T13:08:33.499534+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:906:3
2014-05-05T13:08:33.504110+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-05T13:08:33.431730+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2014-05-05T13:08:33.431732+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-05T13:08:33.431702+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-05T13:08:33.497363+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-05T13:08:33.499525+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
2014-05-05T13:08:33.499527+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-05-05T13:08:33.510483+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2014-05-05T13:08:33.510935+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls MotionTherapy
2014-05-05T13:08:33.511048+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2014-05-05T13:08:33.511376+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
2014-05-05T13:08:33.511525+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2014-05-05T13:08:33.511677+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cwd /app
2014-05-05T13:08:33.511823+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
2014-05-05T13:08:33.512018+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
2014-05-05T13:08:33.512181+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2014-05-05T13:08:33.513568+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2014-05-05T13:08:33.513674+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
2014-05-05T13:08:33.513765+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2014-05-05T13:08:33.514040+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not ok code 0
2014-05-05T13:08:33.497678+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-05-05T13:08:33.509594+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 8
2014-05-05T13:08:33.509809+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the MotionTherapy@0.0.1 start script.
2014-05-05T13:08:33.510340+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the MotionTherapy package,
2014-05-05T13:08:33.510575+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2014-05-05T13:08:33.509373+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! MotionTherapy@0.0.1 start: `node server.js`
2014-05-05T13:08:33.509681+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2014-05-05T13:08:33.510720+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2014-05-05T13:08:33.510894+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2014-05-05T13:08:32.252658+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2014-05-05T13:08:35.158739+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-05-05T13:08:35.132782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-05-05T13:08:46.488494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=25ce25df-73cf-44d4-a900-b779b87210bc fwd="194.81.199.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T13:08:48.425892+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=374e68f2-a953-4151-8501-b4faf0cd8c68 fwd="194.81.199.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T13:10:02.187303+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by plimbsuni@gmail.com
2014-05-05T13:10:31.191709+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=6e3b207d-4549-474b-b830-d2333fb4a319 fwd="194.81.199.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T13:10:33.563751+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=faa3e382-edd2-4fe7-87ca-638be45fac7f fwd="194.81.199.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T13:12:23.041518+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=16327123-615e-4886-81dd-59076bfc7e01 fwd="80.74.98.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T13:12:24.054516+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=70617391-d024-4ffc-a207-e9ec398102f3 fwd="80.74.98.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T13:12:24.201792+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=004fb266-1556-4ddf-bb68-16f015ee5957 fwd="80.74.98.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T13:13:45.035442+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=0127e27f-4dea-4cf0-beb5-4de53dafc144 fwd="194.81.199.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-05T13:13:45.502856+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=stormy-brushlands-6191.herokuapp.com request_id=542ec48e-e9b9-4f36-ae0b-f7d851c57453 fwd="194.81.199.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Check your `heroku logs`...

Comment: Yeh I don't really understand what is going on...it runs locally, here is what i get with heroku logs @YuvalAdam please see above ^^^